# Simple Prolog delete from list

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

(This is NOT a coursework question. Just my own personal learning.)

I'm trying to do an exercise in Prolog to delete elements from a list. Here's my code :

```
deleteall([],X,[]).
deleteall([H|T],X,Result) :- 
    H==X,
    deleteall(T,X,Result).
deleteall([H|T],X,[H|Result]) :- deleteall(T,X,Result).
```

When I test it, I first get a good answer (ie. with all the Xs removed.) But then the backtracking offers me all the other variants of the list with some or none of the instances of X removed.

Why should this be? Why do cases where H==X ever fall through to the last clause?

Comment: Thank you interstar for asking how to delete, I was doing the same excercise. I haven't had used == operator before in prolog. I have understood your solution. We can improve by replacing X to _ in the first sentence to avoid singleton variable. Also we should put ! operator on the second and third cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last clause says that when removing `X` from a list, the head element may stay (independently of its value). Prolog may <s>use this clause at any time it sees fit, independently of whether the condition in the preceding clause is true or not</s> backtrack into this clause if another clause fails, or if you direct it to do so (e.g. by issuing `;` in the top-level to get the next solution). If you add a condition that the head element may not equal `X`, it should work.

Edit: Removed the incorrect assertion I originally opened with.

Comment: Oh! For some reason I kind of assumed it was. (Ie. the listing counted.) That would explain a LOT of problems I'm having.

Comment: -1. Prolog clauses are executed in left-to-right, top-down order, although the interpreter may backtrack into following clauses upon failure.

Comment: The order of clauses is not entirely unordered. They are considered in a fixed order. But your point behind is true: As long as there is no `!` in your clauses, every clause will contribute its answers. Only non-termination and errors may hide further answers.

Comment: @larsmans: I removed the first sentence. The middle sentence is probably not entirely correct; feel free to edit it.

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks. At least, the very opening of my initial sentence was correct: "It's been a while since I did any prolog" ;-)

Comment: OK. Thanks for the correction. Though actually I'm no longer sure quite what you're saying. If the order *is* important, how come we ever execute the last clause in situations where X == H. Won't the second clause have already caught that?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what "backtracking" means. I thought it tracked all alternative correct solutions. Does it actually just mean "after matching one clause try matching the next"?

Answer (score 7):

When you are using `(==)/2` for comparison you would need the opposite in the third rule, i.e. `(\==)/2`. On the other hand, such a definition is no longer a pure relation. To see this, consider `deleteall([X],Y,Zs), X = Y.`

For a pure relation we need `(=)/2` and `dif/2`. Many Prologs like SWI, YAP, B, SICStus offer `dif/2`.

```
deleteall([],X,[]).
deleteall([H|T],X,Result) :- 
    H=X,
    deleteall(T,X,Result).
deleteall([H|T],X,[H|Result]) :-
    dif(H,X),
    deleteall(T,X,Result).
```

Look at the answers for `deleteall([X,Y],Z,Xs)`!

Edit (after four years):

More efficiently, but in the same pure vein, this can be written using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600) and `(=)/3`:

```
deleteall([], _X, []).
deleteall([E|Es], X, Ys0) :-
   if_( E = X, Ys0 = Ys, Ys0 = [E|Ys] ),
   deleteall(Es, X, Ys).
```

Comment: @Dunes: Please read the link to see that  it **is** `(=)/3` and not `(=)/2`!

Comment: None of your `=` predicates have three terms though. They're all in the form `A = B`. Perhaps you should provide a link to documentation for `(=)/3` and what is does in your answer.

Comment: There is exactly a link above to document this! It is `if_/3` that calls it. The exact call to `(=)/3` will be `call(A = B, T)` which results in `call(=(A,B,T))`.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, `=/3` is not part of the ISO. I think it's sicstus specific. As is if/3, which I didn't initially realise. Though SWI seems to have a compatibility module with it, but it's not implemented as you suggest. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/sicstus.pl?show=src#if/3 Might be best to state which dialect you using for the more efficient answer.

Comment: It's `if_/3` and not `if/3`. And no dialect is involved here. All is defined in the link above! Please read it. And SWI is definitely not a good reference w.r.t ISO.