# Please Help on some basics on prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program that deletes any occurrence of a member in a given list, as bellow:

```
deleteall(1,[1,2,3,1,3,2,5],Out)                
Out= [2,3,3,2,5]
```

How can I do that? This is my attempt:

```
deleteall(X,[],[]).                
deleteall(X,[H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- deleteall (X,T1,T2).
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We want to help, but we like to see you make an attempt first. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I forget it, but now I change it

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441527/simple-prolog-delete-from-list/6441803#6441803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following. You were missing a condition in your original program.

```
deleteall(_,[],[]).
deleteall(X,[X|T1],T2) :- deleteall(X,T1,T2).
deleteall(X,[H1|T1],[H1|T2]) :- not(X=H1), deleteall(X,T1,T2).
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work for me. I am using win prolog 4.7 .

Comment: Well, I'm using XSB-Prolog. What error are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't back any error, just say no

Comment: Try invoking with deleteall(1,[1,2,3,1,3,2,5],O).

Comment: out is a constant, not a variable