# Can anyone help me in writing a prolog program for deleting a list?

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

Ex: If I have been given two list [1,4,3,2,5,6] and [1,2,3] the final list should be [4,5,6].

i.e.,  `Del([1,4,3,2,5,6], [1,2,3], Result).`
       ----should output Result=[4,5,6].

I have tried something like this:

```
 delete1(A, [A|B], B).
 delete1(A, [B, C|D], [B|E]) :- delete1(A, [C|D], E).
```

But the output I'm getting is by deleting the element being passed as an parameter and not a list.

Output:

```
delete1(a,[a,b,c,d],Res).

   (0) Call: delete1(a,[a,b,c,d],_h210) ?
   (0) Exit: delete1(a,[a,b,c,d],[b,c,d]) ?

Res = [b,c,d]
```

Can anyone please help me how to go about this ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441803/772868) for a pure version.

Answer (score 2):

Pure and simple: Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) in tandem with `list_nonmember_t/3`!

Like we did with [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), we define `list_nonmember_t/3` based on [`if_/3` and `(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
list_nonmember_t([],_,true).
list_nonmember_t([E|Es],X,T) :-
   if_(E=X, T=false, list_nonmember_t(Es,X,T)).
```

Let's put it together!

```
?- tfilter(list_nonmember_t([1,2,3]), [1,4,3,2,5,6], Xs).
Xs = [4,5,6].                         % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 0):

```
del1([], _, []).
del1([A|L], B, R) :- member(A, B), del1(L, B, R).
del1([A|L], B, [A|R]) :- not(member(A,B)), del1(L, B, R).
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. But the program you gave throws error. Here is the output:

| ?- del1([1,2,3,4],[3,2],R).
   (0) Call: del1([1,2,3,4],[3,2],_h226) ? 
   (1) Call: see(0) ? 
   (1) Exit: see(0) ?  
   (2) Call: default_error_handler(error(existence_error(procedure,usermod : member / 2),[],[[39947184,39952640,39952512,41346368,40949824,41346496,40028960,41354720,40680192,40679216,40072096,39940656,40628976,39956000,40072096,39940656]])) ?
End XSB (cputime 0.02 secs, elapsetime 26.96 secs)

Comment: For del1([1,2,4,5],[2,3],Res), the output should be Res=[1,4,5].

Answer (score 0):

So your `delete1` is a good start, it allows to delete single element from the list, but it is not handling all of the cases. For example the lists that are not containing the element to be deleted.
So the right one would be :

```
delete1(_, [], []).
delete1(A, [A|B], B).
delete1(A, [C|B], [C|E]) :- delete1(A, B, E).
```

and then using this, you can define your `del1` by applying `delete1` recursively on the whole list:

```
del1([], _, []).
del1(L, [], L).
del1(L, [H|T], R) :- 
    delete1(H, L, R1),
    del1(R1, T, R).
```

And of course you can use builtin list predicates as stated in the other answer.